# Wildstar housing: Garden LvL 2

Tags: wildstar

I recently found a Set for Rank 2 Gardening for my Wildstar House. After upgrading it and planted some seed and leaving my house I waited the acquired 35min for my seed to grow but when I came back everything was gone. All seeds (and I had some very expensive ones) where completely lost...

Is the gardening system buggy at the moment? Or did I do anything wrong? At Level 1 I had no problems at all.

Comment: Is your house set to public? If so people can visit it and harvest your seeds for you.

Comment: Hey, nice idea! But no, it's private and I don't have any neighbours nor did I get a message saying "your seed was stolen". :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did nothing wrong. This is a quite [common](https://forums.wildstar-online.com/forums/index.php?/topic/42274-tier-2-garden-bugged/) [bug](https://forums.wildstar-online.com/forums/index.php?/topic/66702-tier-2-garden-seeds-disappear/), although I haven't seen any official response on it yet.

I had the same issue after I upgraded to tier 2, my tier 3 is currently working without any issues though. Best you can do right now is report it via the /bug command.

Comment: Thanks mate, so there isn't any responce by carbine about this yet? Can anyone confirm this?